# Get Date from MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm storing DATE on MySQL Workbench with value '2018-06-13' and '2018-07-07'. When I get it from nodejs server, I got some confusing:

```
  con.query(stm, function(err, results){
    if (err) throw err;
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
        var d = new Date(results[i].date);
        console.log(d);
        console.log(d.getDate())
    }
    console.log(results);
```

Here what I get:

```
2018-06-12T17:00:00.000Z
13
2018-07-06T17:00:00.000Z
7
[ RowDataPacket {
date: 2018-06-12T17:00:00.000Z},
RowDataPacket {
date: 2018-07-06T17:00:00.000Z } ]
```

Anyone know why date on server is 13 and 7, but it was subtracted by 1 when received on server?

Comment: "The getDate() method returns the day of the month for the specified date according to **local** time." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate

Comment: @MarkMeyer That doesn't completely explain it.

Comment: I just want to know why there is difference between date on mysql and when I get it on server

Comment: Is the column really `DATE` or is it actually `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`?  This is almost certainly a timezone issue.

Comment: It DATE, I set the time zone of mysql to my local time_zone but its stil; the same

Comment: What is `results[i].date`

Comment: MySQL dates don't have a time component, so I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @MarkMeyer results[i].date get the 'date' column

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Im asking about date, Im not talking about time

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen doesn't the node driver convert Dates from the DB to date-time strings.

Comment: @MarkMeyer And now you have just answered the question :-) ... so probably that driver is also shifting the time zone from UTC to the local time, which appears to be 7 hours behind the actual MySQL server.

Comment: I've already changed time zone on mysql to my local time_zone

Comment: That doesn't matter @NguyenHoangVu-K11FUGHCM. Your server is just sending a date like `2018-06-12`. Node converts that to `2018-06-13 00:00:00` *local time*. If you are somewhere like Vietnam  then that is equal to `2018-06-12:17:00 Z`. To your local day is 13 even thought the UTC day is 12.

Comment: I got it, so how can I fix it?

Comment: Try  `var d = Date(results[i].date)` without `new`

Comment: It just return my current time :)

Comment: I want to get the same date stored on mysql

Comment: And I just wonder why the mysql send "2018-06-12T17:00:00.000Z" while the vaule stored on mysql is "2018-06-13"

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is simple, what the server returns is UTC. What `Date(results[i].date)` returns is UTC + or - the time difference between UTC and your current time zone.
I ran

```
Date('2018-06-12T17:00:00.000Z')
```

and the Output was

```
"Tue Jul 17 2018 16:10:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

which is the time in IST i.e UTC+ 5hrs 30mins